# "Evaluate" doesn't work as a javascript function name in Mozilla firefox and google-chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I wrote a simple html file with just a javascript function. It worked in IE but not in frefox and chrome. The code was:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function evaluate()
{
alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form >
<table id="tbl">
 <tr align="right">
  <td><input  id="__JAVA_Evaluate" type="button" value="evaluate!" onclick="evaluate()"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After a while I understood that it was not possible to define a function with the name evaluate() in the Firefox and chrome. 
And it is enough to rename the function. I wonder that is other function name which are reserved in Firefox and chrome and how we could be aware about this reserved keys?

Comment: FYI, Firefox 4b9 complains `uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments" nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/ :: onclick :: line 1" data: no]` when clicking the button, Chrome says nothing (and both don't reach the breakpoint I set within `evaluate`. I can't find anything about `evaluate` as a reserved keyword, though.

Comment: This is the exact reason why you should always work inside your own namespace ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting that [global functions and properties](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_global.asp) are not listed in Mozilla's official reserved word list:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Absolutely don't use any variables or function names that are in either of the previous lists. As you found, there may be additional peculiarities per-browser.

Comment: Reserved words are not the same as already existing functions.

Comment: That's because those aren't reserved according to the ECMAScript spec; that list on (horrible) W3Schools.com doesn't mention `document.evaluate`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reference for this function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate

Comment: I disagree - document.* isnt global and therefore shouldnt interfere, if it was window.evaluate then i would agree. for example, document.contentType exists, although i cant access any global named contentType, so too evaluate shouldnt resolve to document.evaluate

Comment: @davin: Apparently event handlers attached using HTML attributes run in the scope of `document`, as using `onclick="window.evaluate()"` works.

Comment: @davin: Not so strange, though, I realize now: when an event handler that is attached using an HTML attribute is fired, `this` is set to the element that triggered the event. As DOM elements all reside below the `document` object, that scope is reached *before* `window` (the global object in web browsers) is.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: according to http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html the reason is not because of `this` but because `document` is added to the scope chain, although maybe that's what you meant. moreover, the link says that this is not a documented standard. wow, i didnt realise there were scope differences between inline and not.